# Unable to import mysql.connector in a Python venv session

Tags: mysql, connectivity, python

I've used *venv* to create a virtual environment for Python 3.5.2. I have installed the `mysql.connector`. The connector works fine as long as I am not in an activated *venv* environment.

```
from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
from python_mysql_dbconfig import read_db_config
```

With these statements I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fetchone.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mysql.connector import MySQLConnection, Error
ImportError: No module named 'mysql.connector'
```

I have searched for a solution but most are dated several years ago. Like I said, the `mysql.connector` is located and works fine outside of the *venv* environment

Comment: Is ***venv*** short for ***virtual environment***?

Comment: Yes...that's the python module name

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check out the following article:

**[Can not get mysql-connector-python to install in virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22100757/1820861)** (Stackoverflow)

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22829966/1820861) states the following:

> Several things. There is an inconsistency in package naming so you may want to do:
>
> ```
> pip search mysql-connector
> ```
>
> to find out what it is called on your platform. I got two results `mysql-connector-python` and `mysql-connector-repackaged`.
>
> so try this first:
>
> ```
> pip install mysql-connector-python
> ```
>
> this may additionally give an error like this:
>
> ```
> Some externally hosted files were ignored (use 
>   --allow-external mysql-connector-python to allow).
> ```
>
> so finally this should do the job:
>
> ```
> pip install mysql-connector-python --allow-external mysql-connector-python
> ```

Comment: DEPRECATION: --allow-external has been deprecated and will be removed in the future. Due to changes in the repository protocol, it no longer has any effect.

Answer (score 0):

The following command solved the issue for me.

`pip install mysql-connector-python-rf`

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34168651/4709762) expands a little on the differences between `mysql-connector-python` and the `-rf` suffixed variant.